# What's the fastest way of hiding and showing all the rows of a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a filter for querying our html table (10k+ rows). My initial thought was to first hide *all* the rows, and then unhide the rows that match the specific query. If the filter is removed, then show all rows.

Is this a more optimal way of writing the hide/show all rows functions?

```
// optimize this!
this.hideAllRows = function() {
    nodes = document.getElementById('table_body').children
    for(var i=0, i_max=nodes.length; i<i_max; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.display="none"
    }
}

// optimize this!
this.showAllRows = function() {
    nodes = document.getElementById('table_body').children
    for(var i=0, i_max=nodes.length; i<i_max; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.display=""
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just hide the whole `<tbody>`?

Comment: @Pointy And how are you going to show some of the rows in it then?

Comment: I would like to hide all rows in one pass, and unhide the rows that match the query (via a hashmap, that maps the criteria to the specific #id). I hide the table row by row, so i can then unhide. Hiding the tbody wouldn't work, since I need to later unhide the specific rows.

Comment: Do you have any indication that your current method is too slow? If so, does it look like a lot of redrawing is going on while you hide the items? If so, hiding the tbody first, then hiding/showing the rows, and then showing the tbody again might reduce the number of repaints needed, and thereby increase performance.

Comment: OK First: 10,000 rows is too many rows by any reasonable usability standard. Second: probably the fastest way to do it would be to add `class` values to the rows, and then set classes on the `<table>` or `<tbody>` that, via CSS rules, would show some rows and not others.

Comment: is adding/setting classes faster than changing the style attribute?

Comment: @vgoklani well it certainly *might* be faster, since you can cause the layout of many elements to change with just one DOM update.

Comment: @Pointy: could you please expand on your answer; I rewrote the code by adding/removing classes, but the difference was very subtle.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to implement a pagination or "infinite" scroll feature. This would remove the need to render 10k dom elements simultaneously. You could render them in batches, as the user scrolls, or chunk them into pages.

Alternatively, you can try pulling the table out of the dom, hiding rows, then reinserting it. This will prevent unneccesary reflows/paints/etc.

Comment: I'm interested in pursuing both approaches. What would you recommend for infinite scroll? If I hide a div, and then write to it, does that really reduce/prevent un-necessary repaint?

Comment: I always roll my own infinite scroll. It's not super complicated. Simply detect scroll position and compare to the height of the scroll container. When it's near the bottom, load more content. I don't think just hiding a div will have the same benefits of removing it from the dom.

Comment: Do you have an example I could work from. I like the idea of rolling my own, but I would like a reference :) Thanks!

Comment: None that I am allowed to share. Anyway, if you create an infinite scroller from scratch, you will learn much more from it.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb using a pure javascript `for` loop is faster than using jQuery `.each()` but your basic selection using the `.getElementById()` and `.children` property is already well optimized.

However iterating through 10k+ elements in the browser is always going to be slow. Showing and hiding elements is best suited to record sets in the 100s not the 1000s.

Why not make an AJAX request that returns data (presumably from a database) already formated as `<tr>...some <td>s here....</tr><tr>...some <td>s here....</tr>`?

That way you can let your database do all the heavy lifting when it comes to filtering, they are optimized to do this. It keeps your code is simple, your bandwidth is reduced, and your DOM manipulation is kept to a minimum.

Whenever you want to apply a filter, you can make a `$.ajax` request.

```
function filter(criteria){

    $.ajax({
        url : myDataUrl,
        type : "POST",
        data : {criteria : criteria}
    })
    .success(function (data){
        $("#table-body").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion but I prefer to keep my database clean :) we also do real-time queries, so I need to solve this problem on the client side. But thanks for your input

Comment: This article has  some good points on client-side vs server-side rendering http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/